# COPY failed: no source files were specified with github actions

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions

### Error Description

While running command `git push`, I am getting following error: **COPY failed: no source files were specified**

### Dockerfile

Dockerfile is like it:

```
# 拉取node:14作为构建工具
FROM node:14 AS build
# 工作目录为 app
WORKDIR /app
# 将以package结尾的json文件拷贝
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -g pnpm
# 执行 安装依赖
RUN pnpm install
# 将 ts配置文件拷贝过去
COPY tsconfig.json ./
# 将public目录拷贝过去
COPY public public/
# 将src目录拷贝过去
COPY src src/
# 执行构建脚本
RUN pnpm run build
# 拉取nginx
FROM nginx:alpine
# 将构建好的文件夹拷贝到nginx中
COPY --from=build /app/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html

# 暴露端口9567
EXPOSE 9567
# 运行nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

### Github Actions Yaml

dev.yml(github actions)is like as shown below::

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions
name: Deploy Web De
# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the main branch
  push:
    branches: [main]
  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:
# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "deploy-web-dev"
  deploy-web-dev:
    environment:
      development
      # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on:
      ubuntu-latest
      # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install pnpm
        uses: pnpm/action-setup@v2
        with:
          version: 6
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pnpm install
      - name: Build web dev
        run: pnpm run build

      - name: Log in to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Reset dockerignore
        run: |
          echo "*" > .dockerignore
          echo "!dist" >> .dockerignore

      - name: Build and push images
        env:
          COMMIT_SHA_TAG: development-${{ github.sha }}
          LATEST_DEV_TAG: dev-latest
          PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_REGISTRY: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_REGISTRY }}
          PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD }}
        run: |
          docker build . -t cloud-music:$COMMIT_SHA_TAG -t cloud-music:$LATEST_DEV_TAG -t $PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_REGISTRY/cloud-music:$COMMIT_SHA_TAG -t $PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_REGISTRY/cloud-music:$LATEST_DEV_TAG
          docker push cloud-music:$COMMIT_SHA_TAG
          docker push cloud-music:$LATEST_DEV_TAG

          docker login -u $PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_USERNAME -p $PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD $PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_REGISTRY
          docker push $PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_REGISTRY/cloud-music:$COMMIT_SHA_TAG
          docker push $PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_REGISTRY/cloud-music:$LATEST_DEV_TAG
```

### Jobs Log

Jobs log:

#### Error Position

**Error in line 23**

```
1
Run docker build . -t cloud-music:$COMMIT_SHA_TAG -t cloud-music:$LATEST_DEV_TAG -t $PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_REGISTRY/cloud-music:$COMMIT_SHA_TAG -t $PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_REGISTRY/cloud-music:$LATEST_DEV_TAG
2
  docker build . -t cloud-music:$COMMIT_SHA_TAG -t cloud-music:$LATEST_DEV_TAG -t $PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_REGISTRY/cloud-music:$COMMIT_SHA_TAG -t $PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_REGISTRY/cloud-music:$LATEST_DEV_TAG
3
  docker push cloud-music:$COMMIT_SHA_TAG
4
  docker push cloud-music:$LATEST_DEV_TAG
5
  
6
  docker login -u $PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_USERNAME -p $PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD $PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_REGISTRY
7
  docker push $PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_REGISTRY/cloud-music:$COMMIT_SHA_TAG
8
  docker push $PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_REGISTRY/cloud-music:$LATEST_DEV_TAG
9
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
10
  env:
11
    PNPM_HOME: /home/runner/setup-pnpm/node_modules/.bin
12
    COMMIT_SHA_TAG: development-6ba24b062419ef744d2642e2f9eee97dabb9a63e
13
    LATEST_DEV_TAG: dev-latest
14
    PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_REGISTRY: ***
15
    PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_USERNAME: ***
16
    PRIVATE_DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD: ***
17
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
18

19
Step 1/12 : FROM node:14 AS build
20
 ---> 903c2c873ea4
21
Step 2/12 : WORKDIR /app
22
 ---> Running in f80bdf0901cf
23
COPY failed: no source files were specified
24
Removing intermediate container f80bdf0901cf
25
 ---> 3221d5124e85
26
Step 3/12 : COPY package*.json ./
27
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

### Project Structure

Here is my project structure.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YBzu.png)

Please help me in solving this error.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Where is that file located? Is your package.json in `dist` directory? Try to update `.dockerignore`, so you provide it to docker build context.

Comment: I shared my project structure.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you might solved this issue. ANyhow my reply is to help others for reference. I too faced the same problem and solved by the following changes made in workflow.yml. You need to mention the docker packages and docker file directory in workflow by cd

workflow at the time of error

```
run: docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag nodejs:$(date +%s)
```

Fix:

```
run: |
    cd app
    docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag nodejs:$(date +%s)
```